# S3 bucket is redirecting to an unknown web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing a problem with S3 static website hosting. 
I have a domain example.com 
I have two buckets -
example.com  (example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com)
www.example.com and (www.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com)

I have my static files in example.com and www.example.com I am using for redirect only.

It looks like www.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com bucket is redirecting to an unknown path ( a webpage that I did not create )
I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: You need to provide some more information. Details of bucket's settings, error messages. Otherwise its only a speculation.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Maybe try to force delete all your caches in a browser or use incognito mode.

Comment: Yes, tried the same and looks working. Not sure what happened for a moment. Thanks Marcin

Comment: Guess maybe had to wait a bit for all DNS propagation to happen.